# Issue calling appcmd from PsExec

Tags: batch-file, psexec, appcmd

The following command to create AppPools in IIS executes fine locally;
    "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd" add apppool /in < "webservice.apppools.2012.xml"

When I try to run it remotely using PsExec it gives me an 'Invalid XML input' error.  From what I can tell the command is coming back to the server I am executing PSEXEC on and getting the xml file from there. This always gives the invalid xml error.  Additionally, I tried copying the xml to the remote server but again, the command comes back to the executing server to get the xml file.  How can I force it to execute on the remote server and use the xml there?  I have tried using -i and -s.

```
%1 = Destination server
%3 = password
set appCmd=\\%1\c$\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd
set tempFolder=D:\deployment\temp

PsExec \\%1 -u administrator -p %3 -h %appCmd% add apppool /in < "%tempFolder%\webservice.apppools.2012.xml"
```

There is nothing wrong with the xml as it works fine locally.

Comment: Does the xml file exist on the target system?  Not sure how PSEXEC handles redirected files.  Looking at some threads that use redirected input with psexec, I am pretty sure the program and file have to exist on the target system.

Comment: I tried copying the xml file to the target system.  If I give a unc path to the file I get the same error.  If I give an absolute path PSEXEC looks for it on the machine I am running it on instead of the machine I am deploying on.

set tempFolder=\\%1\d$\deployment\temp     -UNC
set tempFolder=D:\deployment\temp              -absolute

PsExec \\%1 -u administrator -p %3 -h "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd" add apppool /in < "%tempFolder%\webservice.apppools.2012.xml"

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do with that code.  You should update your question with the code.  It is hard to read the code in comments.  I have no idea what you are trying to do with `-UNC`. I do not see any code that is copying the file to the D: drive on the target system.

Comment: Updated my question